# How to remove missing values when calculating weighted grouped percentages

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to calculate weighted percentages without missing values. Any advice on how the below code can be modified so that NA values are not part of the analysis?

```
df <- data.frame(
    wave = rep(c(1,2),6),
    gender = rep(c("m", "f", NA),4),
    exp = rep(c("c", "e", NA),4),
    weights = rnorm(12, 1, .5)
)

> head(df)
  wave gender  exp   weights
1    1      m    c 0.6556222
2    2      f    e 0.6462524
3    1   <NA> <NA> 1.1822910
4    2      m    c 1.3842665
5    1      f    e 0.9438269
6    2   <NA> <NA> 1.4405539

 library(srvyr)
 library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, gender, exp) %>%
  as_survey_design(1, weight = weights) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(wave, key, value)  %>%
  dplyr::summarise(prop_weighted=srvyr::survey_mean(na.rm=TRUE)*100) 

# A tibble: 12 × 5
# Groups:   wave, key [4]
    wave key    value prop_weighted prop_weighted_se
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>            <dbl>
 1     1 exp    c              27.0             18.1
 2     1 exp    e              38.7             21.7
 3     1 exp    NA             34.3             20.3
 4     1 gender f              38.7             21.7
 5     1 gender m              27.0             18.1
 6     1 gender NA             34.3             20.3
 7     2 exp    c              27.6             19.8
 8     2 exp    e              20.3             14.8
 9     2 exp    NA             52.1             23.0
10     2 gender f              20.3             14.8
11     2 gender m              27.6             19.8
12     2 gender NA             52.1             23.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to drop those rows before you calculate:

`df %>% drop_na()` will drop rows with NA values. If you want to specify which columns you can use this `df %>% drop_na(gender, exp)` to be explicit

Comment: I should have picked a better example, but in my full data, some vars have NAs while others don't. Dropping rows will lead to losing data.

Comment: It does not need to, you can do the entire tidy manipulation above, after dropping the NA and then `%>%merge(df,...)` using the index as the identifier and get back all lost rows. Just use this part to do the computations.